# How to get difference between current date and other date ( java.util.Date) in years in Java

Tags: java, date

How to get difference between current date and other date ( java.util.Date) in years in Java

I have incoming java.util.Date object and I need to get how many whole years are between them.

I tried Joda's time Period but I have to create joda's time object. Is there other way to calculate this difference. Way to get millis and try to convert it to years doesn't count leap years.

Comment: How exactly do you want leap-years to count?

Comment: My question doesn't related to scala or how to convert to Joda Time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since most of the methods in the `Date` class are deprecated, you can use [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
Calendar firstCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
firstCalendar.setTime(firstDate); //set the time as the first java.util.Date

Calendar secondCalendar = Calender.getInstance();
secondCalendar.setTime(secondDate); //set the time as the second java.util.Date

int year = Calendar.YEAR;
int month = Calendar.MONTH;
int difference = secondCalendar.get(year) - firstCalendar.get(year);
if (difference > 0 && 
    (secondCalendar.get(month) < firstCalendar.get(month))) {
    difference--;
}
```

With the `if` statement I'm checking if we have dates like `June, 2011` and `March, 2012` (for which the whole year difference would be 0). Of course, I'm assuming that `secondDate` is **after** `firstDate`.

Comment: Updated, thanks for the note. :)

Answer (score 2):

Starting with JDK 8, you can get a Duration between 2 dates. Even better, some ChronoUnits, like years, as you requested.

```
Instant t1, t2;
...
long years = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(t1, t2);
```

Forget about Date, 3rd party jars(Joda Time is cool, but let's do it in a standard way) and Calendars. JDK 8 is the future.

Embrace it !
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using joda.

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(a);  
DateTime end = new DateTime(b); 
difference = Years.yearsBetween(start, end).getYears();
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert a [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to a [org.joda.time.DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object is trivial, because DateTime has a constructor for this:

```
 DateTime jodaTime = new DateTime(javaDate);
```

You can then pass these to [org.joda.time.Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) and call getYears() on the result to get the number of whole years between these two dates:

```
 public int getYearDifference (Date begin, Date end) {
     return new Period(new DateTime(begin), new DateTime(end)).getYears();  
 }
```